# I am getting "GetLastError command failed: getLastError command is not supported" while trying to insert document in Robo3T under collections

Tags: database, mongodb, document, robo3t

I am getting error while trying to insert document in Robo3T but the document is successfully getting added to the list after clicking on OK.

Error message : **GetLastError command failed: getLastError command is not supported**

Not sure as the same version of Robo 3T is working on my other machine and also I am currently using Robo3T ver:1.4

Comment: I see the same error while trying to update the document. But the document is not updated after clicking on OK.

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same.
This is because the `getLastError` command has been deprecated in MongoDB and is no longer supported. (as of MongoDB 4.4)

Comment: any solutioons?

Answer (score 3):

As `getLastError` has been deprecated, make sure your robo3T supports your mongodb version. I was also using Robo3T 1.4.4 and had same problem. I installed Studio3T, new updgraded version of Robo3T and this solved my problem.